# Get Octopus Deploy release number from a C# WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, octopus-deploy

We use Octopus Deploy to deploy our apps. It would be very useful if my WinForm app could display the Octopus Deploy release number at run time.

Is it possible to setup Octopus Deploy so that it sets a variable stored in the app.config to the Octopus.Release.Number system variable, so I can retrieve the release number at run time?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Variable substitution in files with Octopus 2.3](http://octopusdeploy.com/blog/variable-substition-in-files) and [System Variables](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/System+variables) you can:

- Use `<add key="OctopusReleaseNumber"value="#{Octopus.Release.Number}" />` in your config
- Enable variable substitution
- Configure this for the appropriate configuration file

Then you can read the substituted value from code.

Comment: Ahh that is a cleaner solution than using transforms!

Comment: If it works at least, I just pieced this together from the docs, don't have it running here.

Comment: @Layoric so feel free to undelete your answer, people may not be running Octopus 2.3 or it may even not work. :)